# Windows 8.1 - Bluescreen BUGCODE_NDIS_DRIVER

Tags: windows-8.1

I tried to install a hardware I've installed in my previous computer under Windows 7, basically an external network card with antenna, but when I try to use it, after installed it I get this bluescreen error:

**BUGCODE_NDIS_DRIVER**

I don't know if it's possible to fix it, any useful information?

PS: If this isn't the best Stack forum, please guide me to the right one.

Comment: MS explains the bugcheck here and gives tips how to debug it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff559221%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I found this website, but I don't have any error code. I can't really debug further.

Comment: you must open the dump file with Windbg

Answer (score 0):

There is some technical information on [Windows Dev Center - Hardware](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559221(v=vs.85).aspx) on this bugcheck.  Driver developers can find the cause from the bugcheck code and parameters.

I can duplicate the `BUGCODE_NDIS_DRIVER` blue screen on my Windows 8.1 developer box fairly easily by opening two different VPN tunnels.  Luckily, I don't need both running at the same time, so my solution is "don't do that".

For example, I open SonicWALL Global VPN Client to connect to one network.  Then, I open the Cisco VPN client to connect to another.  The crash happens almost immediately.

Answer (score -2):

If you have two active network card, deactivate one, that is all.